# Wrap Some Child Elements with a Parent Div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent-child

How can I wrap a variable number of child divs with a new parent div in Javascript?

```
<div class="child">1</div>  
<div class="child">2</div>  
<div class="child">3</div>  
<div class="child">4</div>  
<div class="child">5</div>
```

Need to place a div container around 1, 2 & 3 for one user and around 3, 4 & 5 for another user and so on.  The parent container will always be around consecutive child divs.

EDIT:
Have tried to [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)  which works fine for 1 child but not multiples.

Comment: I don't think you can wrap #3 in two different parent elements

Comment: @robjez I believe the OP wants to wrap 1, 2, and 3 for one user, and 3, 4, and 5 for a different user. Not wrap both groups simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few ways you can do this using [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/):

```
$('.child:gt(1)').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">'); // wraps 3, 4, and 5
$('.child:lt(3)').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">'); // wraps 1, 2, and 3
$('.child').slice(1,4).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">'); // wraps 2, 3, and 4
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qhvL5frn/)**